# How to use counta function with two columns (or)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I would like to use `counta` function to count rows that are not empty based on column A or B.

In other words.. if either column `A` **or** `B` not empty,  it should be counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use

```
=QUERY(INDEX(A1:A&B1:B),"select count(Col1)",0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A&B:B<>"")))`

ROW(A:A) gives us "something" to count.

By concatenating each row-cell of A:A with the corresponding row-cell of B:B, we form one string, which we can *evaluate* as one string and thus count as one string.

Comment: It didn't work
//https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GHPlQiMdmHBqAVETDmFsrYS4jjVWnaEjqrfb8rS7Vco/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please see update to formula, swapping the first A:A for ROW(A:A). I updated your sheet.

Comment: That's good but it will always return a value of 1 if all cells are empty!. What about using countif (two criteria like A:A<>""&B:B, A:A&B:B<>"")

Comment: See updated formula with IFERROR wrap included. If this does the trick, please be sure to mark the post as "Best Answer" to signal to others that the issue has been fully addressed.

Comment: That solved the issue. I need to read it slowly to digest and understand the function of iferror and row

Comment: The reason that you were getting a 1 with all blanks is that the FILTER produced no results, which throws an #NA error. Since an error of any kind is "something," COUNTA was counting the error as 1. IFERROR(   ) with no second argument simply instructs Sheets to return null (i.e., nothing) instead of an error. As for ROW(A:A), again, it just gives something constant to FILTER based upon, since very row, filled or blank, will have a row number. Again, if this satisfies your posted request, please mark my post as "Best Answer" to signify that it has been resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and solved as well

```
=countifs(A1:A,"<>")+countifs(A1:A,"",B1:B,"<>")
```

Comment: Good work Hassan :)